# et al. does not appear

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm using `\usepackage[options]{natbib}` and `\citet` (IEEE journal) for writing the author name, but unfortunately when  I run it just the name of the author appears without the et al.  What should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Specifically, I'd have questions about the .bib entry as well -- I assume there are enough authors to warrant an et al., but that's not obvious yet.

Comment: You need to show us the full contents of the the bib entry in question. The precise contents of the `author` field within this entry will be of particular interest.

Comment: Without more info, this is unclear I'm afraid.